# How can I write a Mongoose find query that uses another field as it's conditional?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following:

I have a Mongoose model called 'Person'. In the schema for the Person mode, each Person has two fields: 'children' and 'maximum_children'. Both fields are of type Number.

I would like to write a find query that returns Persons when that Persons 'children' value is less that it's 'maximum_children' value.

I have tried:

```
person_model.find({
    children: {
        $lt: maximum_children
    }
}, function (error, persons) {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
});
```

and

```
person_model.find({
    children: {
        $lt: 'maximum_children'
    }
}, function (error, persons) {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
});
```

I'm doing something wrong in trying to specify the field name that I want to compare 'children' against.

Answer (score 1):

OK.

I found a solution, just after I posted this question.

The answer seems to be:

```
person_model.find({
    $where: "children < maximum_children"}, function (error, persons)
}, {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
});
```

Seems to work OK, although it seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

`$where` must execute its JavaScript conditional against every doc so its performance can be quite poor.  Instead, you can use [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/#aggregation-pipelines) to include a new field in a `$project` stage the indicates whether the doc matches or not and then filter on that:

```javascript
person_model.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        isMatch: {$lt: ['$children', '$maximum_children']},
        doc: '$$ROOT'
    }},
    {$match: {isMatch: true}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, doc: 1}}
], function(err, results) {...});
```

This uses [`$$ROOT`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) to include the original doc as the `doc` field of the projection, with a final `$project` used to remove the `isMatch` field that was added.

`results` looks like:

```javascript
{
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54d04591257efd80c6965ada"),
        "children" : 5,
        "maximum_children" : 10
    }
}, 
{
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54d04591257efd80c6965add"),
        "children" : 5,
        "maximum_children" : 6
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the added `doc` level of the objects you can use `Array#map` on `results` like so:

```javascript
results = results.map(function(item) { return item.doc; });
```

Which reshapes `results` to put them back into their original form:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d04591257efd80c6965ada"),
    "children" : 5,
    "maximum_children" : 10
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d04591257efd80c6965add"),
    "children" : 5,
    "maximum_children" : 6
}
```